# Schur multipliers

Tags: finite-groups, group-cohomology, computational-algebra

I'm working on the characterization of simple groups by their prime graphs. In my work I need the Schur multipliers of the almost simple groups related to L_3(49). Unfortunately we don't have access to MAGMA package in my university and I could not do this by GAP.

Comment: Have you tried using the [MAGMA calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/)?

Comment: Can this information be derived from [Atlas of Finite Groups](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/) ?